# Can't parse 0:30 AM/PM correctly in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

So, I was trying to convert a string to a datetime in PHP using the code written below.

When I run this code, the result is `1:00` instead of `0:30` as it should be. But when I tried converting `1:30`, it works fine. Is this a bug in PHP?

```
$start = date("H:i", strtotime("0:30 AM")); 
var_dump($start);
return 0;
```

Comment: `strtotime('0:30 AM')` yields `false` actually; either drop the AM or use 12:30.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no bug. In the 12-hour clock, midnight and midday are represented by 12, not 0. So, if you've an AM or PM indicator, the times should be "12:30 AM" or "12:30 PM".

In the 24-hour clock, there's no AM or PM indicator, so "0:30" or "12:30" would be the equivalents.

With an invalid date, `strtotime` is probably returning returning false (or -1, in earlier versions of PHP) and things are going downhill from there.